# NASM basic input-output program crashes

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, rhel

Following this thread, [How do i read single character input from keyboard using nasm (assembly) under ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305005/how-do-i-read-single-character-input-from-keyboard-using-nasm-assembly-under-u) ,I'm trying to compile a program that echoes the input in NASM.
I've made following files:

my_load2.asm:

```
%include "testio.inc"
global _start
section .text
_start: mov eax, 0
call canonical_off
call canonical_on
```

testio.inc:

```
termios:        times 36 db 0
stdin:          equ 0
ICANON:         equ 1<<1
ECHO:           equ 1<<3

canonical_off:
        call read_stdin_termios

        ; clear canonical bit in local mode flags
        push rax
        mov eax, ICANON
        not eax
        and [termios+12], eax
        pop rax

        call write_stdin_termios
        ret

echo_off:
        call read_stdin_termios

        ; clear echo bit in local mode flags
        push rax
        mov eax, ECHO
        not eax
        and [termios+12], eax
        pop rax

        call write_stdin_termios
        ret

canonical_on:
        call read_stdin_termios

        ; set canonical bit in local mode flags
        or dword [termios+12], ICANON

        call write_stdin_termios
        ret

echo_on:
        call read_stdin_termios

        ; set echo bit in local mode flags
        or dword [termios+12], ECHO

        call write_stdin_termios
        ret

read_stdin_termios:
        push rax
        push rbx
        push rcx
        push rdx

        mov eax, 36h
        mov ebx, stdin
        mov ecx, 5401h
        mov edx, termios
        int 80h

        pop rdx
        pop rcx
        pop rbx
        pop rax
        ret

write_stdin_termios:
        push rax
        push rbx
        push rcx
        push rdx

        mov eax, 36h
        mov ebx, stdin
        mov ecx, 5402h
        mov edx, termios
        int 80h

        pop rdx
        pop rcx
        pop rbx
        pop rax
        ret
```

Then I run:

```
[root@localhost asm]# nasm -f elf64 my_load2.asm 
[root@localhost asm]# ld -m elfx86_64 my_load2.o -o my_load2
```

When I try to run it i get:

```
[root@localhost asm]# ./my_load2
Segmentation fault
```

Debugger says:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/asm/my_load2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000b1 in canonical_off ()
```

Can someone explain why is it crashing without on "import" step?
Also, I am running RHEL in Virtualbox under Win7 64 bit. Can this cause problems with compilation?

Comment: In the code you post there is no symbol `write_stdin_termios` defined. You may have the un-complete version of code posted.

Comment: You never exit your program.

Comment: Fixed that. I try to compile full code.

Comment: The fact I dont exit does not explain why it crashes on canonical_off, but not afterwards.

Comment: Your `termios` structure appears to be in `section .text` - read only memory. Would putting it in `section .data` help?

Comment: Shouldn't the emulation mode for the ``ld`` command be ``elf_x86_64`` instead of ``elfx86_64``?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, let's address the issue of not exiting, as mentioned by Daniel. Let's comment out the two `call` instructions, so the program essentially does nothing:

```
%include "testio.inc"
global _start
section .text
_start: mov eax, 0
;call canonical_off
;call canonical_on
```

When we run this:

```
$ ./my_load2 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It still dies! Daniel is right - you need to exit:

```
%include "testio.inc"
global _start
section .text
_start: mov eax, 0
;call canonical_off
;call canonical_on

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

This time:

```
$ ./my_load2
$
```

No segfault. So let's uncomment the `call`s:

```
%include "testio.inc"
global _start
section .text
_start: mov eax, 0
call canonical_off
call canonical_on

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

And run it again:

```
$ ./my_load2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

We get a segfault again. But at least we can be (fairly) sure that's coming from inside one of the `call`ed routines.

Running the executable with `strace` is also quite informative:

```
$ strace ./my_load2
execve("./my_load2", ["./my_load2"], [/* 57 vars */]) = 0
setsockopt(0, SOL_IP, 0x400080 /* IP_??? */, NULL, 0) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x40008c} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The `setsockopt` line is due to the `ioctl` request that happens in `read_stdin_termios`. `strace` tells us the return value was `EFAULT`. The `setsockopt(2)` man page tells us this happens when:

> The address pointed to by optval is not in a valid part of the process address space.

Actually this is telling us that the block of memory into which the `termios` structure is written is read-only. Frank is correct; everything in the program - including the `termios` space, and all the code - is in the read-only `.text` section. You can see this with:

```
$ objdump -h my_load2.o

my_load2.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000000cd  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001c0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
```

i.e. there's only one section, `.text`, and it's `READONLY`.

The line that actually causes the segfault, however, is this one:

```
and [termios+12], eax
```

because it also tries to write to the (read-only) `termios` memory.

The quickest way to fix this is to put the `termios` memory in the `.data` section, and everything else in the `.text` section:

```
section .data

termios:        times 36 db 0

section .text

stdin:          equ 0
ICANON:         equ 1<<1
ECHO:           equ 1<<3

canonical_off:
        call read_stdin_termios

[...]
```

(`stdin`, `ICANON`, and `ECHO` can be in the read-only `.text` section, because they're just used as constants - i.e. we don't write to those bits of memory.)

Having made these changes:

```
$ ./my_load2 
$
```

The program runs and exits normally.

Comment: 64-bit code should generally avoid `int 0x80`.  Use `mov eax, 60` / `syscall` to make an `_exit(edi)` system call.