# Disable echo and set raw terminal mode via ANSI escape sequence or X11 escape sequence

Tags: terminal, escaping, ansi-escape

Is there possibility to disable echo (except `ESC[8m` which only hides text) programatically in remote terminal? Any equivalent for `stty -echo`?

Is there also any escape command to enable raw mode (equivalent of `stty raw`) in remote terminal? Without raw mode getchar works only after ENTER press.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that there is not a way to do this just using escape codes of any kind. You will have to take a look at `termios.h`. If you need to do this low-level and can't use C, see [How do i read single character input from keyboard using nasm (assembly) under ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305005/how-do-i-read-single-character-input-from-keyboard-using-nasm-assembly-under-u), other than that, try searching for "non-canonical terminal input" ([Canonical vs. non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/canonical-vs-non-canonical-terminal-input))