# How to read some characters from keyboard and display them on screen in amd64 GAS?

Tags: assembly, att, gnu-assembler

Have no clue, I read [How do i read single character input from keyboard (键盘) using nasm (assembly) under ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305005/how-do-i-read-single-character-input-from-keyboard-using-nasm-assembly-under-u/3380413#3380413), **and I can't write executable program.**

My expected effect is:

```
> ./program
  please input some character: abcdefg
  abcdefg
```

I examined [ioctl syscall](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/), and use `man termios`, but I can't found about the second parameter `cmd` introduction, such as `TCGETS 0x5401`, and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: It's quite complicated to read the keyboard *directly* (`/dev/event/`something), equally hard to draw on the screen.  Normally you just `read()` stdin and `write()` stdout, letting a terminal or terminal emulator turn key codes into characters.  i.e. you implement `cat`, or one system call of it.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, I just want to `read()` stdin and `write()` stdout,  but I can't Implement  it also!